# Google-Mock/Test compiler error with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, googlemock

I am compiling a google test project and the compilation is successful. However I am getting the following error during linking with my project.
Is this related to how the linking is ordered I wonder?

```
CMakeFiles/Test.dir/Test1.cpp.o: In function `GetTimeMock::GetTime(int*, _time_data*)':
Test1.cpp:(.text._ZN20GetTimeMock19ENET_GetTimeEPiP19_time_data[_ZN20EnetGetTimeMock19ENET_GetTimeEPiP19_time_data]+0x4a): undefined reference to `testing::internal::UntypedFunctionMockerBase::UntypedInvokeWith(void const*)'
```

Here is what my CMAKE looks like

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)

include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake)

# Set compiler to c++17
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

ExternalProject_Add(
    GoogleTest
    URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/6ce9b98f541b8bcd84c5c5b3483f29a933c4aefb.zip
    URL_MD5 "0bca4c8c9fc2d06634185057a905ff11"
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external"
    BUILD_COMMAND "$(MAKE)"
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic")

set(SOURCE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../source)
set(UNIT_TEST_MAIN ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/unit_test_main.cpp)
set(GTEST_MAIN ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/lib/libgtest_main.a)
set(GTEST ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/lib/libgtest.a)
set(GMOCK_MAIN ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/lib/libgmock_main.a)
set(GMOCK ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/lib/libgmock.a)

    set(SOURCE
       ${UNIT_TEST_MAIN}
       ${SOURCE_PATH}test.cpp
       ${SOURCE_PATH}/test1.cpp
       ${SOURCE_PATH}/test2.cpp
       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar.cpp
       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar1.cpp
       ${STUB_PATH}/platforms/k64f/src/fstub.cpp
    )

    include_directories(
       ${SOURCE_PATH}/include
       ${SOURCE_PATH}/Files
       ${SOURCE_PATH}/
    )

    set(target "Test")
    add_definitions(${DEFINITION})
    add_executable("${target}" ${SOURCE})
    add_dependencies("${target}" GoogleTest)

    target_link_libraries("${target}"
       "${GMOCK_MAIN}"
       "${GMOCK}"
       "${GTEST_MAIN}"
       "${GTEST}"
       pthread)
```

Comment: I see no `include_directories` for GTest headers. It seems, that you use **system** GTest headers, but link with a **manually-built** GTest library. This could be a reason of "undefined reference". Also, you forgot `project()` call in your `CMakeLists.txt`. While CMake does it implicitely when see project-related command (like `add_executable`), you loose setting of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable: it is rewritten at the `project()` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev What changes in the CMake would be required to fix this. I'm not exactly sure what to do.

Comment: It should be something like `include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/include)` for make headers from manually-built GTest to be available for your executable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you very much that worked